# java(android) - unexpected error TabHost

Tags: android, class, android-manifest, android-tabhost

I want to use TabHost, but my app has stopped unexpectedly. I don't really know, what the problem is, i'am a beginner android programmer.

I use 4 java classes, one for TabHost, and three another classes.

UnitCount class:

```
     package com.eqsec.csaba;


     import android.content.Intent;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.app.TabActivity; 

    public class UnitCount extends TabActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Hosszusag.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("hosszusag").setIndicator("Husszusag")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tomeg.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tomeg").setIndicator("Tömeg")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Urtartalom.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("urtartalom").setIndicator("Űrtartalom")

                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("hosszusag");
}

  }
```

LogCat

[logcat](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/120120/problems_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

I have 3 another classes called Urtartalom.class, Hosszusag.class, Tomeg.class.
Should i change anything in android manifest? Thanks!

Comment: do not underestimate the power of the logcat ...

Comment: Can you please post the LogCat?

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe You can show us your layout xml file and provide a stacktrace from LogCat?

Comment: looks like you are using custom id for tabhost instead of "android:id="@android:id/tabhost". anyway, show us layout xml file for tab activity

Comment: ohh shit, really.. u have right ;) thanks!!! it's work!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. Maybe You can show us your layout XML file and provide a stack trace from LogCat?

---

It looks like you are using custom id for tabhost instead of `android:id="@android:id/tabhost`.  Anyway, show us layout XML file for tab activity.

Answer (score 0):

The most common error is that the R file is not being properly generated (based on your logcat).

Just delete R.java and rebuild the project, it worked for me once.